# Replacing SD card reader on a Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: components, soldering, raspberry-pi, sd

I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi B+. However, the micro SD Card reader had a defective spring loading mechanism, so the card would not lock in place (a new Pi is now on the way!)

However, I would like to try to see if there's any way I could salvage this Pi at all. I took the broken mini SD carder off:

[image]

And was thinking of replacing it by soldering connections from [this](https://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_2082935_-1#) SD card reader. Does anyone know if this will work? Or have any insights if they've done somethings imilar before? Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't try it. Ask the RPi folks where you can find a replacement part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that you can do.

1) Ask the R-Pi organization if they can supply a replacement micro-SD socket.

2) Strip a micro-SD socket from a dead cellphone or other piece of gear that has a compatible socket.

3) (last resort) solder wires directly from the pads to the SD card.  The problem is that this is a sort of one-way trip for the SD card - it may not make reliable connection into a SD socket if you need to change the contents of the SD card.

On the other hand - if the contents of the SD card don't ever need to be changed externally, soldering it permanently into the circuit is perfectly acceptable.